# using setstate to update my database changes with refresh button

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, pull-to-refresh

i use RefreshIndicator and its working well but couldnt make it functional for my database, i think my setstate is wrong , can you help me to use setstate to make it functional , here is my product page..

```
class FeaturedProducts extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
  _FeaturedProductsState createState() => _FeaturedProductsState();-
}


class _FeaturedProductsState extends State<FeaturedProducts> {
final keyRefresh = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
  List<ProductModel> products = [];

 @override 
void initState() {
super.initState();

  loadProducts();
 }

Future loadProducts() async {
keyRefresh.currentState?.show();
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 4000));



setState(() => this.products = products);,
}

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final productProvider = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context);

 return RefreshIndicator(
 keyRefresh: keyRefresh,
 onRefresh: loadProducts,

child: ListView.builder(
 scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
 itemCount: productProvider.products.length,
 itemBuilder: (_, index) {
 return FeaturedCard(
 product: productProvider.products[index],


  );
  }));
 }
}
```